# Necesito actualizar dos <p:fieldset /> toggleables pero cuando selecciono uno, ya no se actualiza el segundo

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

Hola tengo un problema con dos p:fielset que se contraen, cuando selecciono sólo uno, este se contrae y el segundo se desplega, si lo vuelvo a presionar, el primero se despliega y el segundo se contrae, pero al seleccecionar el segundo, este despliega pero no actualiza el primero y dejan de actualizarse.

```
<p:outputPanel id="filtros">                
                <h:form >                    
                        <p:fieldset
                    id="primerfield"
                    legend="Primer Filtro"
                    toggleable="true"
                    collapsed="#{mbController.numero==2}"
                    >
                    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{mbController.actionButon}" update="@([id$=filtros])" process="@this"/>
                    <p:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" layout="grid">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Primer Filtro"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{mbController.numero}"/>                
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:fieldset
                    id="segundofield"
                    legend="Segundo Filtro"
                    toggleable="true"
                    collapsed="#{mbController.numero==1}"
                    >
                    <p:ajax event="toggle" update="@([id$=filtros])" listener="#{mbController.actionButon}" process="@this"/>
                    <p:panelGrid id="panelDos" columns="2" layout="grid">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Segundo Filtro"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{mbController.numero}"/>                
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:commandButton value="Comand B" action="#{mbController.reset}"/>                                             
            </h:form>                
            </p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo,
Lo que usé fue un srcipt que mandara a llamar los toggles cuando se cierran.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var contFstAct= 0;
        function manejarToggle(invocador) {
            contFstAct++;
            if (contFstActivo % 2 == 1) {
                console.log("Entre")
                var fstInactivo = (invocador == 1) ? segundofield: primerfield;
                if (fstInactivo.stateHolder[0].value === 'false') {
                    fstInactivo.toggle();
                    fstInactivo.stateHolder[0].value = 'true';
                } else {
                    contFstAct++;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```